# Microsoft Access Form.Delete event - message displaying twice

Tags: vba, ms-access

When using the Form.Delete event on a continuous form, the message is displaying twice.

My Access version is 2111 (Build 14701.20226)

Has anyone else run into this?

```
Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer) 
    Cancel = True 
    MsgBox "This record can't be deleted." 
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope. Tested and I get message only once. Access 2010.

Comment: nope for access 2016

Comment: try making a new form and then cut in pasting the parts of the current form and seeing when and especially if the problem occurs again

Comment: Do you have a sub form? It might be the culprit.